# SQLITE : Segmentation Fault 11 on upgrading to Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I've updated to Xcode 7.
When I try to build, the build fails with a "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11".
I delete the sqlite framework, and reload again SQLite (clean the project) and the same error occurs.

Also delete the foder /library/developer/xcode

On Xcode 6 work perfectly.

Some can help

Error

```
CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
cd /Users/Jose/Documents/MoBank/MoBank/Dependencies/SQLite
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -whole-module-optimization -module-name SQLite -Onone -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -target arm64-apple-ios8.0 -g -module-cache-path /Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options -application-extension -embed-bitcode-marker -enable-testing -I /Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoBank-dhjycuvnfedturdcstfvosmlqogn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F /Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoBank-dhjycuvnfedturdcstfvosmlqogn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -c -num-threads 8 /Users/Jose/Documents/MoBank/MoBank/Dependencies/SQLite/SQLite/Database.swift /Users/Jose/Documents/MoBank/MoBank/Dependencies/SQLite/SQLite/Statement.swift /Users/Jose/Documents/MoBank/MoBank/Dependencies/SQLite/SQLite/Value.swift /Users/Jose/Documents/MoBank/MoBank/Dependencies/SQLite/SQLite/Expression.swift /Users/Jose/Documents/MoBank/MoBank/Dependencies/SQLite/SQLite/Functions.swift /Users/Jose/Documents/MoBank/MoBank/Dependencies/SQLite/SQLite/Query.swift /Users/Jose/Documents/MoBank/MoBank/Dependencies/SQLite/SQLite/FTS.swift /Users/Jose/Documents/MoBank/MoBank/Dependencies/SQLite/SQLite/RTree.swift /Users/Jose/Documents/MoBank/MoBank/Dependencies/SQLite/SQLite/Schema.swift -output-file-map /Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoBank-dhjycuvnfedturdcstfvosmlqogn/Build/Intermediates/SQLite.build/Debug-iphoneos/SQLite.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SQLite-OutputFileMap.json -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoBank-dhjycuvnfedturdcstfvosmlqogn/Build/Intermediates/SQLite.build/Debug-iphoneos/SQLite.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SQLite.swiftmodule -Xcc -I/Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoBank-dhjycuvnfedturdcstfvosmlqogn/Build/Intermediates/SQLite.build/Debug-iphoneos/SQLite.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoBank-dhjycuvnfedturdcstfvosmlqogn/Build/Intermediates/SQLite.build/Debug-iphoneos/SQLite.build/SQLite-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoBank-dhjycuvnfedturdcstfvosmlqogn/Build/Intermediates/SQLite.build/Debug-iphoneos/SQLite.build/SQLite-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoBank-dhjycuvnfedturdcstfvosmlqogn/Build/Intermediates/SQLite.build/Debug-iphoneos/SQLite.build/SQLite-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoBank-dhjycuvnfedturdcstfvosmlqogn/Build/Intermediates/SQLite.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoBank-dhjycuvnfedturdcstfvosmlqogn/Build/Intermediates/SQLite.build/Debug-iphoneos/SQLite.build/SQLite-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoBank-dhjycuvnfedturdcstfvosmlqogn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -Xcc -I/Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoBank-dhjycuvnfedturdcstfvosmlqogn/Build/Intermediates/SQLite.build/Debug-iphoneos/SQLite.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoBank-dhjycuvnfedturdcstfvosmlqogn/Build/Intermediates/SQLite.build/Debug-iphoneos/SQLite.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoBank-dhjycuvnfedturdcstfvosmlqogn/Build/Intermediates/SQLite.build/Debug-iphoneos/SQLite.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SQLite-Swift.h -import-underlying-module -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/Jose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoBank-dhjycuvnfedturdcstfvosmlqogn/Build/Intermediates/SQLite.build/Debug-iphoneos/SQLite.build/unextended-module-overlay.yaml -Xcc -working-directory/Users/Jose/Documents/MoBank/MoBank/Dependencies/SQLite
```

:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Download the SQLite project from:
  https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/tree/swift-2
- Delete the current SQLite.xcodeproject, and replace from the downloaded.
- Add SQLite.framework at Linked Frameworks and Libraries and Embedded Binaries
- Clean and build